Currently, I'm not visiting (a) gym
Which sentence is grammatically correct:
Currently, I'm not visiting a gym.

vs.
Currently, I'm not visiting gym.

Or maybe both are correct?

They're both syntactically valid, but the article-less version isn't common. Also see this usage chart. We nearly always talk about going to the gym, even if "the" gym hasn't been mentioned earlier in the conversation. It's the same as going to the pub, going to the shop.

Does this answer your question? Definite article for a particular purpose that's more important than individual place or its location Note that gym is specifically mentioned several times there in the question, answer, and comments.

Not your question, but I did want to clarify that when we talk about "visiting" a gym, that only means a single visit at the present time; so the sentence "Currently, I'm not visiting a gym" means "Right now, I am not inside a gym." If you want talking about not habitually visiting a gym on a regular basis, you would use a different construction like, "Currently, I don't go the gym."

Can you say I eat apple? I eat [bread] roll? In English, for countables, you need an determiner or an s.  Also, we say: going to a gym, not visiting...

You need the "a". In English, you need an article in front of every noun, except when the noun is a proper name, or when it is preceded by a number or a few other adjectives that can take the place of the article, like "this".
So for example, you could say, "Currently, I'm not visiting Gold's Gym." Because Gold's Gym is a proper name.
You could say, "I'm not visiting this gym." "This" makes an article unnecessary.
You could say, "I'm not eating two bananas." You don't need an article with a number. (I suppose you could say, "I'm not visiting two gyms." Having a number of gyms might make sense in some context.)
Otherwise, you need an article.
Oh, another exception is titles and headlines, where articles are sometimes omitted. Like, "Senator Jones Not Visiting Gym".
